# My linux terminal is getting stuck

Tags: hard-drive

My system was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working. I tried to troubleshoot, but I could not understand the problem. I am using WSL (ubuntu).

**WHEN I AM USING cd /mnt/d the system gets stuck**

I am sorry this for this, I have tried whatever internet suggested, please help me

```
ls -l
total 4168
drwxr-xr-x 2 ianke ianke    4096 Jan 16  2022

ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1690 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
 1704 pts/14   00:00:00 top
 1706 pts/14   00:00:00 ps

ls -l /bin/cd
ls: cannot access '/bin/cd': No such file or directory
ls -l /bin/cd-
cd-create-profile  cd-fix-profile     cd-iccdump         cd-it8

stat -f /mnt
  File: "/mnt"
    ID: fedc9aa3bd65bc57 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 65793553   Free: 64431228   Available: 61071689
Inodes: Total: 16777216   Free: 16652708

         nvram   ram2   sdc     tty11   tty22  tty33  tty44  tty55  tty9   vfio

/dev$ ls /dev/sd*

/dev/sda  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdc


:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
[sudo] password for ianke:
mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.

:~$ lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0   256G  0 disk
sdb    8:16   0 342.4M  1 disk
sdc    8:32   0   256G  0 disk /

~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist.

~$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0  256G  0 disk

~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 256 GiB, 274877906944 bytes, 536870912 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda1
Possibly non-existent device?
```

Comment: what does "gets stuck" mean? freezes up? shows an error? just keeps loading? crashes? describe what happens please.

Comment: /mnt/d is your windows D drive, which is automatically mounted for you as /mnt/d by Microsoft's windows interoperability modifications. you don't have to mount anything. If it's crashing, that's either a problem with the interop stuff, or with your drive itself.

Comment: can you access your `D:\ ` drive in Windows? can you do `ls /mnt` and show that? The rest of what you posted is irrelevant, since the drive is being exposed to you by Windows, and isn't something you have to deal with on your own.

Comment: 1. It just freezes up. I uninstalled the ubuntu app and installed it again after this issue, the same problem still persists.
2. Yes I never mounted it before, but as I am facing the problem I tried mounting it.  (I don't understand what could be the issue with the drive)
3. I can not access it in wsl. 


after uninstalling, I can't even start ubuntu from windows terminal 

PS C:\Users\ianke> ubuntu
ubuntu:CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\ianke> wsl

[it is stuk at this command for a long time]

Comment: when i started the ubuntu

Run as admistrator: This is the message that i got
An error occurred mounting one of your file systems. Please run 'dmesg' for more details.  
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".                                                  See "man sudo_root" for details.
ls /mnt  
c  d  wsl  wslg

When accessed d or c drive it showed nothing.

Then I tried it in WSL (inbuilt) it is working.

Comment: did you run `dmesg` for more details?

Comment: I deleted the old Ubuntu and installed a new one. It is working fine so far. Thank you so much for these comments.